# How to extend an adminhtml grid directly?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I'm trying to extend my admin product grid with a specific column.

What class should I extend for this? `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget`? In Block/Widget theres also a Grid ( `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` ) file... I'm a little confused.

Comment: Try this https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Maybe I can get the correct answer from myself.